# Linearly Scale Between RGB values

Tags: scale, rgb

Is there an easy mathematical relationship for scaling between two distinct RGB (3-tuple) values. Say I want to scale from red to green `(1,0,0)` to `(0,1,0)`. Or say the values are more complex how do I linearly scale from `(22,183,19)` to `(199, 201, 3)`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple algorithm that will generate an array of RGB tuples that represent a linear transition.  I noticed you had `javascript` tags in your profile, so I went with that.  I chose to use the max distance between any pairs to determine the number of steps rather than using a fixed number of steps (but obviously that's trivial to change).

```
function generateLinearTransition(start, end) {
    var rDiff = end.r - start.r;
    var gDiff = end.g - start.g;
    var bDiff = end.b - start.b;
    var steps = Math.max(Math.abs(rDiff), Math.abs(gDiff), Math.abs(bDiff));
    var rStepSize = rDiff / steps;
    var gStepSize = gDiff / steps;
    var bStepSize = bDiff / steps;
    var tuples = [start];
    var current = start;
    for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
        current = {
            r: current.r + rStepSize,
            g: current.g + gStepSize,
            b: current.b + bStepSize,
        };
        tuples.push({
            r: Math.floor(current.r),
            g: Math.floor(current.g),
            b: Math.floor(current.b)
        });
    }
    tuples.push(end);
    return tuples;
}

var a = {
    r: 22,
    g: 183,
    b: 19
};

var b = {
    r: 199,
    g: 201,
    b: 3
};

var results = generateLinearTransition(a, b);

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var current = results[i];
    console.log("(" + current.r + "," + current.g + "," + current.b + ")");
}
```

As an aside, your example of `(1,0,0)` and `(0,1,0)` are both essentially black, so there won't be much transition there.  If you used `(255,0,0)` (red) and `(0,255,0)` (green), respectively, you'd get a longer transition.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jstricker/2u4c5tq1/).

Answer (score 0):

You could find the difference between each value in each tuple by substracting one from the other, divide each of those differences by the number of "steps" to get an incremental delta for each value, per step, and then at each step add that delta.

For example, to scale from `(22, 183, 19)` to `(199, 201, 3)` in, say, 4 steps:

```
199 - 22 = 177; 177 / 4 = 44.25
201 - 183 = 18; 18 / 4 = 4.5
3 - 19 = -16; -16 / 4 = -4
```

So at each step, you'd add `44.25` to the first value (r), `4.5` to the second value (g), and `-4` to the third value (b).  So you'd go from `(22, 183, 19)` to `(66.25, 187.5, 15)` to `(110.5, 192, 11)` to `(154.75, 196.5, 7)` to `(199, 201, 3)`.

Basically, treat each component separately, and scale linearly from one to the other, and combine.